# Is there way to get users public details in google-plus using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-plus

I'm trying to get users public details in google-plus. I have only users public URL. Is there way to get users public details?

Comment: Looks that way, try reading their documentation: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people

Comment: Thanx @Brant.I read their documentation.But in that case I have to authenticate in front end(pop-up window).I want to run my application in backend code.I couldn't find way for to do like that.

Answer (score 2):

You should use scopes in your request, you can find info here https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#authorization-scopes

Or if you use passport.js you can try somethink like this:

```
passport.authenticate('google',  {
   scope:[ 'email', 'profile'],
   failureRedirect: '/'
 })
```